# Dynamic FROM clause in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, dynamic

I have three statements which work (see below), however I would like to combine the three statements into one dynamic statement where tablea, tableb or tablec is used in the FROM clause depending on the value of col4_value. I can't work out how to do this.

```
UPDATE table1 a 
SET a.price_fx = 
  (SELECT b.price 
   FROM tablea b, table2 c
   WHERE a.client = b.client 
   AND a.dim_value = b.project 
   AND a.price_fx != b.price
   AND b.client = c.client
   AND b.project = c.col1_value
   AND c.col4_value = '11'
   AND c.col5_value = 'KB01');

UPDATE table1 a 
SET a.price_fx = 
  (SELECT b.price 
   FROM tableb b, table2 c
   WHERE a.client = b.client 
     AND a.dim_value = b.project 
     AND a.price_fx != b.price
     AND b.client = c.client
     AND b.project = c.col1_value
     AND c.col4_value = '3'
     AND c.col5_value = 'KB01');

UPDATE table1 a 
SET a.price_fx = 
  (SELECT b.price 
   FROM tablec b, table2 c
   WHERE a.client = b.client 
     AND a.dim_value = b.project 
     AND a.price_fx != b.price
     AND b.client = c.client
     AND b.project = c.col1_value
     AND c.col4_value = '34'
     AND c.col5_value = 'KB01');
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I'm using Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0

Comment: But they 2:nd and 3:rd will wrote over the previous UPDATE...? You have to add WHERE to the UPDATEs.

Comment: Hi Jarlh, I didn't make myself clear. I only run one of the queries depending on the col4_value. My question is: is it possible to have a dynamic FROM clause which would use the correct table depending on the value of col4_value. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Is it just those three col4_values that determine which table is used in the update? If not, what is the logic behind choosing the right table to update from?

Comment: Yes, the logic is only based on the col4_values.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, I would try to solve this using outer joins. Something like the following will likely work (it's hard to validate without sample data).

```
UPDATE table1 t1
SET    t1.price_fx =
          (SELECT CASE t2.col4_value
                     WHEN '11' THEN a.price
                     WHEN '3' THEN b.price
                     WHEN '34' THEN c.price
                  END
           FROM   table2 t2
                  LEFT JOIN tablea a
                     ON     t1.client = a.client
                        AND t1.dim_value = a.project
                        AND t1.price_fx != a.price
                        AND a.client = t2.client
                        AND a.project = t2.col1_value
                  LEFT JOIN tableb b
                     ON     t1.client = b.client
                        AND t1.dim_value = b.project
                        AND t1.price_fx != b.price
                        AND b.client = t2.client
                        AND b.project = t2.col1_value
                  LEFT JOIN tablec c
                     ON     t1.client = c.client
                        AND t1.dim_value = c.project
                        AND t1.price_fx != c.price
                        AND c.client = t2.client
                        AND c.project = t2.col1_value
           WHERE  t2.col5_value = 'KB01');
```

---

You could do this dynamically in PL/SQL using `execute immediate`, but I would try to avoid that solution if possible. Dynamic SQL tends to be more fragile and difficult to maintain.

```
DECLARE
   v_sql VARCHAR2 (2000) := 'UPDATE table1 a 
SET a.price_fx = 
  (SELECT b.price 
   FROM [table_name] b, table2 c
   WHERE a.client = b.client 
   AND a.dim_value = b.project 
   AND a.price_fx != b.price
   AND b.client = c.client
   AND b.project = c.col1_value
   AND c.col4_value = :1
   AND c.col5_value = :2);';
   v_col4_value table2.col4_value%TYPE := '11';
   v_col5_value table2.col5_value%TYPE := 'KB01';
   v_table_name VARCHAR2 (30);
BEGIN
   v_table_name :=
      DBMS_ASSERT.sql_object_name (
         CASE v_col4_value
            WHEN '11' THEN 'tablea'
            WHEN '3' THEN 'tableb'
            WHEN '4' THEN 'tablec'
         END);
   v_sql := REPLACE ('[table_name]', v_table_name);

   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_sql USING v_col4_value, v_col5_value;
END;
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I'll try them out.